# How to render html on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg

Client will fetch json formatted data from server:

```
{"html": "<hr>a<br>"}
```

And I want to render the html code into a div. How can I do that?

And in fact, I want to display the rendered html page inside a wysiwyg editor.

Is there any Opensource wysiwyg(js, html5, or sth) can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question: after you parse your JSON, you can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var div = document.getElementById('example');
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', obj.html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the multiples WYSIWYG editors. I recommend CKEditor. 
For html code into a div, is easy. But we need to view your code to help you better.

Only if you write this:

```
 var json = { "html" : "<a>some html</a>" };
 document.getElementById("theDivID").innerHTML = json.html;
```

Good luck